# ¿Como mantener el estado de un fragment en Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment

Tengo un proyector en Kotlin con la plantilla por defecto de MenuDrawer (Navigation Drawer Activity).

En la pantalla inicial, (Home_fragment) implemente un Slider con esta librería https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

Al iniciar la aplicación esta funciona correctamente y se puede "navegar" por los diferentes fragment que tiene la app. pero al momento de volver al fragment inicial (Home_fragment) la aplicación se cierra.

Al ver el Logcat me sale que el error se produce al volver al Home_Fragment en la lógica del Slider.

Eh tratado de buscar la solución al problema, mantener el estado del fragment, ver librerías, videos, pero no he podido solucionar el problema.

Dejo el código del Home_Fragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.mec.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    var sampleImages = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.slider1,
        R.drawable.slider2,
        R.drawable.slider3,
        R.drawable.slider4,
        R.drawable.slider5,
        R.drawable.slider6,
        R.drawable.slider7,
        R.drawable.slider8,
        R.drawable.slider9
    )

    var cities = arrayOf(
        "Aris",
        "Grand",
        "Habimec",
        "Genimec",
        "Aris",
        "Grand",
        "Habimec",
        "Genimec",
        "Genimec"
    )


    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })



        return root


    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        btn_ver_todo.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_nav_gallery)
        }

        btn_familia.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_familiasFragment)
        }

        btn_hidrobox.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_hidroboxFragment)
        }

        btn_temporizador.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_temporizadoFragment)
        }

        btn_control.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_elementosControlFragment)
        }

        btn_industrial.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_tomasIndustrialesFragment)
        }
        btn_conexion.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_elementosConexionFragment)
        }

        btn_emt.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_EMTFragment)
        }

        btn_tablero.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_CTGFragment)
        }

        btn_sujecion.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_accesoriosSujecionFragment)
        }

        btn_accesorios.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_accesoriosIntaladoresFragment)
        }



//  Slider

        carouselView.pageCount = cities.size

        carouselView.setImageListener { position, imageView ->
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position])
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)

        }
    }


}
```

El Logcat que marca error en la linea 117 (HomeFragment.kt:117)

```
2020-10-02 00:35:52.011 21804-21804/com.example.mec E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2020-10-02 00:35:52.022 21804-21804/com.example.mec E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.RuntimeException: View must set ImageListener or ViewListener.
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView$CarouselPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CarouselView.java:346)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:856)
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView.setData(CarouselView.java:255)
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView.setPageCount(CarouselView.java:437)
       at com.example.mec.ui.home.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.kt:117)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:884)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:827)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:874)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:827)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:190)
       at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2826)
       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2766)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:137)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:353)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4748)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4719)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4401)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4458)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4595)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2512)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2106)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2097)
       at android.vi
2020-10-02 00:35:52.023 21804-21804/com.example.mec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.mec, PID: 21804
   java.lang.RuntimeException: View must set ImageListener or ViewListener.
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView$CarouselPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CarouselView.java:346)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:856)
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView.setData(CarouselView.java:255)
       at com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView.setPageCount(CarouselView.java:437)
       at com.example.mec.ui.home.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.kt:117)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:884)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:827)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:874)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:827)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:190)
       at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2826)
       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2766)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:137)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:353)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4748)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4719)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4401)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4458)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4595)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2512)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2106)
2020-10-02 00:35:52.024 21804-21804/com.example.mec E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2097)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2487)
       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:356)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Ojala alguien me pueda ayudar.

de antemano Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de un tiempo al fin logre dar con el problema y su solución.

En el Logcat en la segunda linea dice "java.lang.RuntimeException: View must set ImageListener or ViewListener."

lo que dice es que hay que hacer por un oyente al "ImageListener" o al "ViewListener"

Así que lo implemente en el **onCreateView**

```
val carouselView = root.findViewById(R.id.carouselView) as CarouselView;
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.size);
        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
```

La lógica del carouselview la implemente afuera del **onViewCreate** con una función

```
var imageListener: ImageListener = object : ImageListener {
    override fun setImageForPosition(position: Int, imageView: ImageView) {
        // You can use Glide or Picasso here
        imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position])
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)
    }
}
```

y finalmente el arreglo

```
 var cities = arrayOf(
        "Aris",
        "Grand",
        "Habimec",
        "Genimec",
        "Aris",
        "Grand",
        "Habimec",
        "Genimec",
        "Genimec"
    )
```

lo elimine.

el código quedo de la siguiente manera

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    var sampleImages = intArrayOf(
            R.drawable.slider1,
            R.drawable.slider2,
            R.drawable.slider3,
            R.drawable.slider4,
            R.drawable.slider5,
            R.drawable.slider6,
            R.drawable.slider7
    )

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it


        })

            //OYENTES CAROUSELVIEW

        val carouselView = root.findViewById(R.id.carouselView) as CarouselView;
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.size);
        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

        return root

    }

        // LOGICA CAROUSELVIEW

    var imageListener: ImageListener = object : ImageListener {
        override fun setImageForPosition(position: Int, imageView: ImageView) {
            // You can use Glide or Picasso here
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position])
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)
        }
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btn_ver_todo.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_nav_gallery)
        }

        btn_familia.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_familiasFragment)
        }

        btn_hidrobox.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_hidroboxFragment)
        }

        btn_temporizador.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_temporizadoFragment)
        }

        btn_control.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_elementosControlFragment)
        }

        btn_industrial.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_tomasIndustrialesFragment)
        }
        btn_conexion.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_elementosConexionFragment)
        }

        btn_emt.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_EMTFragment)
        }

        btn_tablero.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_CTGFragment)
        }

        btn_sujecion.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_accesoriosSujecionFragment)
        }

        btn_accesorios.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_accesoriosIntaladoresFragment)
        }

    }

}
```

Con los cambios mencionados el Slider o CAROUSELVIEW funciona sin problemas y al salir del fragment y al volver al app ya no se cierra.

dejo la solución esperando que a alguien mas le pueda servir.